# How to fix “watch later” button on safari

Tags: ios, safari, youtube, mobile-safari

I have an issue with adding a youtube video to “watch later” playlist for safari. When I click the clock button (watch later), a tab opens. Then, several redirects are performed, and the tab closes. The clock button turns into triangle warning sign. No error messages are shown. But the video is not added to playlist. Clicking on the warning sign does the same.

The symptoms are similar to ones described at https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/a1cczs/comment/eapj6uc . I’ve tried everything from that thread (ignoring the fact that that is macos thread) and nothing helped me.

Workaround for the issue is to open video in app by clicking the title and add it to the playlist from the app. But this is inconvenient.

This functionality worked since ios7 and now it is broken. How can I fix that?

I am using iOS 12.